# take the difference between two excel and copy back to first excel the difference

Tags: excel, vbscript, macros

I was able to create a VBscript which copies from one excel to another but I need help in another problem.

I have two excel worksheet.
There are few rows which are common between the excel ( Unique row is identified by column "id").
I need to copy rows from worksheet2 to worksheet1 which are not present in worksheet1.

Worksheet1

```
id  Product_code Product_Name  City     Country    Price
1    x1           Xbox         Sydney   Australia  100
2    X2           P3           London   UK         100
3    x3           Iphone       Sydney   Australia  100
4    X4           Ipad         London   UK         100
```

Worksheet2

```
 id  Product_code  Quantity  Product_Name  City     Country    Price
    1    x1         10      Xbox         Sydney   Australia  100
    2    X2         30      P3           London   UK         100
    3    x3         20      Iphone       Sydney   Australia  100
    4    X4         10      Ipad         London   UK         100
    5    x5         15      Dell         Sydney   Australia  100
    6    X6         20      HP           London   UK         100
```

Few point to note.

1. "Id" Column unique identifies each record in worksheet.
2. The number of column in worksheet can be different .We just need to copy paste common record.

After I run my VB script my worksheet1 should look like

worksheet1.

```
id  Product_code Product_Name  City     Country    Price
1    x1           Xbox         Sydney   Australia  100
2    X2           P3           London   UK         100
3    x3           Iphone       Sydney   Australia  100
4    X4           Ipad         London   UK         100
5    x5           Dell         Sydney   Australia  100
6    X6           HP           London   UK         100
```

here is my code to copy from one excel to another.
1. Is there anyway I can remove duplicate id

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set Excel1= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\x.xlsm")
Set Excel2= objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\y.xlsm")
Excel1.Worksheets("X").UsedRange.Copy
Excel2.Worksheets("Y").Range("A1").PasteSpecial -4163
Excel1.save
Excel2.save
Excel1.close
Excel2.close
objExcel.quit
set objExcel=nothing
```

Comment: When you say VB script, do you mean VBA, or VBS? Not the same. If you are not sure, then I assume it is VBA. Also, what have you tried? If you post some code, we will gladly help, but we won't do your work for you for free...

Comment: I mean VBS. I just have code to copy from one sheet to another . I couldn't figure out to find difference between two worksheet @vacip. added my code to question.

Comment: Oh, well done then. Actually, Excel has a build-in remove duplicates function. You can call that from you VBS. I suggest recording a macro, and using that code. With a little modification, it will fit your VBS script.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is to copy data from both sheets and paste in output sheet and then delete duplicate rows from output sheet

```
    '---1 first copy the data from sheet1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Usedrange.Copy
    '---2 paste in output sheet
    Sheets("output").Activate
    'Select the target range
    Range("A1").Select
    'Paste in the target destination
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    '---3 select second sheet and delete the 1st row header
    Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    ' delete qunatity column
    Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
    '---4  copy the data from sheet2
    Sheets("Sheet2").usedrange.Copy
    'Activate the destination worksheet
    '---5 paste in output sheet
    Sheets("output").Activate
    ourputrowscount=Sheets("output").usedrange.rows.count
    'Select the target range
    Range("A"& ourputrowscount+1).Select
    'Paste in the target destination
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    '---6 remove duplicate rows in column 1
    Set Rng = Sheets("output").usedrange
    Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Copy-paste is never the fastest. It is one of the slowest thing you can do in VBA... Try directly making two ranges equal or copy using parameters, or do anything just avoid the clipboard...

Comment: The number of columns is not same in  both sheets.Few column are common which  need to be copied from sheet 2 to sheet 1

Comment: if the columns are not same, then delete the columns which are different. i updated the code to delete the qunatity column

Comment: @vacip I modified code litte bit and everything is working fine except        Excel2.Worksheets("output").Range("A1:C500").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)                                                                                                                        This throws an error. If you know of anything wrong please let me know Thanks